# Unable to Sign In to Visual Studio Online from Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

I am trying to connect with my organizational Visual Studio Online repository from Visual Studio Online. This has made me really confused.

My company has created an account for me, for example, test@mycompany.com.

This is an office 365 email which has been added to the Visual Studio Online repository. When in browser I type, mycompany.visualstudio.com and enter the password then it takes me to the Visual Studio Online Dashboard and I can see the projects which are assigned to me.

I have installed a fresh copy of Visual Studio 2015 (I have also tried the same steps with Visual Studio 2013). At the first time I start the Visual Studio 2015 then it asks me to Sign-In to the Visual Studio account (which I believe is different from the Visual Studio Online account). When I enter my company email and password then it says,

```
We don't recognize this user ID or password
```

So here I enter my personal email suppose, myemail@outlook.com

After this, I follow these steps,

1 - On the Menu bar, I click "Team" and then "Manage Connections"
2 - It then opens up the Team Explorer where this is mentioned,

```
To connect to a Team Project not listed on the Connect page, click Manage Connections.  The Team Project will be listed on the Connect page after you connect the first time.
```

3 - I click "Manage Connections" and it opens up a popup window "Connect to Team Foundation Server".

4 - Under the "Select a Team Foundation Server" there is my personal email listed, myemail@outlook.com

5 - I click "Servers" and it opens up another popup "Add/Remove Team Foundation Server". Here I again click "Add" which opens up another popup "Add Team Foundation Server".

6 - I enter mycompany.visualstudio.com in the textbox for "Name or URL of Team Foundation Server" and click "Ok".

7 - This opens up another Dialog "Choose an account" where my personal email is selected, myemail@outlook.com

8 - I click "New" and now it opens another popup which says "Work or school, or personal Microsoft account" and asks for email and password

9 - Here I enter my company email which has access to the Visual Studio Online repository i.e. test@mycompany.com and enter the correct password.

10 - When I click "Sign In" after entering email and password then it gives me following error,

```
We don't recognize this user ID or password
Be sure to type the password for your work or school account
```

Again when I enter the same email and password in the browser for url "mycompany.visualstudio.com" then it sign me in but not from Visual Studio 2015.

I know I could just mentioned the error by saying that this error is displayed from Visual Studio but still I mentioned all the steps which I performed so that anyone who sees that I am doing something not correct at any step then they can point that out. Its just strange for me that I can Sign In successfully from the browser but not from the Visual Studio.

Important ! I am using Windows 8.1 and logged in with my personal account "myemail@outlook.com" in the windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue.  As silly as this sounds, I had to indicate it was a personal account instead of a work or school one.

Comment: Wow. It worked. Yes it is really silly. I don't understand the reason behind it but it is connected now. I tried so many different things and struggled for two weeks. Deleting cache, Cleaning Registry, Re-Installing Visual Studio but none worked but this.